# Is there any risk associated with using the same passphrase on two different wallets both hosted on blockchain.info?

Tags: security, blockchain.info, passphrase, salt

Does blockchain.info use any salt with the passphrase?

I.e., is there any risk associated with using the same passphrase on two different wallets **both hosted on blockchain.info**?

**edit**: of course blockchain.info doesn't even keep the hash of the passphrase, as opposite to traditional login systems, so it might not make sense to use a salt in the first place... or does it?

Answer (score 1):

The risk is that, if a hacker gets a hold of one, then they've gotten a hold of both. Or at least If I had one passphrase, it would be my first guess for the second.

However I dont think there is any inherent technical problem for blockchain.info.